# Is it possible to convert Pointer Coordinates to Map Coordinates (Location / Geocoordinates)?

Tags: c#, geolocation, position, bing-maps

I am removing a pushpin from a Bing Map in response to a RightTapped event on the pushpin:

```
private void PinRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    if (null != p)
    {
        DataLayer.Children.Remove(p); // "DataLayer" is the name of the Bing Maps MapLayer
    }
}
```

...but I also want to remove the corresponding Location from the list of locations (photosetLocationCollection) I'm managing. I thought of something like this:

```
private void PinRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    if (null != p)
    {
        DataLayer.Children.Remove(p);
        // Remove it from the location list, too
        int locToRemove = PhotraxUtils.GetIndexFor(args.GetPosition());
        if (locToRemove > -1)
        {
            App.photosetLocationCollection.RemoveAt(locToRemove);
        }
    }
}

private int GetIndexFor(Location _loc)
{
    int unfound = -1;
    Location loopLoc;
    for (int i; i < App.photosetLocationCollection.Count; i++)
    {
         loopLoc = App.photosetLocationCollection[i];
         if ((loopLoc.Latitude == _loc.Latitude) && (loopLoc.Longitude == _loc.Longitude))
         {
             return i;
         }
    }
    return unfound;
}
```

...but alas, "GetPosition" does not return the "world" Location but the screen location, IOW a Point instead of a Location (which, of course, makes sense, when you think about it, but I wasn't really). As the rainforest-dwellers note [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.righttappedroutedeventargs.getposition.aspx), the RightTappedRoutedEventArgs' GetPosition method "Returns the x- and y-coordinates of the pointer":

```
public Point GetPosition(
  UIElement relativeTo
)
```

...(not the pushpin's geocoordinates).

So: *Is* there a way to determine the geocoordinates on which the pushpin sits, or convert the screen coordinates to map coordinates somehow?

### UPDATE

Based on BMW's (the [Bing Map Whisperer](http://www.lulu.com/shop/ricky-brundritt/location-intelligence-for-windows-store-apps/ebook/product-21500370.html)'s) answer, this should work:

```
private void PinRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    if (null != p)
    {
        DataLayer.Children.Remove(p);
        // Remove it from the location collection, too
        int locToRemove = MapLayer.GetPosition(p);
        int locCollIndex = PhotraxUtils.GetIndexFor(locToRemove);
        if (locCollIndex > -1)
        {
            App.photosetLocationCollection.RemoveAt(locCollIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll try it out tomorrow.

### UPDATE 2

Using BMW's thoughts, and updating the code as necessary, this seems to work:

```
private void PinRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    if (p != null)
    {
        DataLayer.Children.Remove(p);
        // Remove it from the location list, too
        Location locToRemove = MapLayer.GetPosition(p);
        int locCollIndex = GetIndexFor(locToRemove);
        if (locCollIndex > -1)
        {
            App.photosetLocationCollection.RemoveAt(locCollIndex);
        }
    }
}

private int GetIndexFor(Location loc)
{
    int locIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < App.photosetLocationCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        Location l = App.photosetLocationCollection[i];
        //if ((loc.Latitude == l.Latitude) && (loc.Longitude == l.Longitude)) <= which way is better, "==" or ".Equals"?
        if ((loc.Latitude.Equals(l.Latitude)) && (loc.Longitude.Equals(l.Longitude)))
        {
            locIndex = i;
            return locIndex;
        }
    }
    return locIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not grab the coordinate information from the pushpin. That's the coordinate you are likely using in your collection. Try something like this:

```
int locToRemove = MapLayer.GetPosition(p);
DataLayer.Children.Remove(p);
```